# Использование библиотеки классов на c# через c++/cli

Tags: c#, dll, c++-cli

Всем доброго времени суток!

Ситуация такая: имеется библиотека классов на c#, которую надо использовать из проектов на delphi и с++. Я не являюсь разработчиком ничего из вышеперечисленного. Моя задача в том, чтобы написать обёртку на c++/cli для классов исходной библиотеки. С cli сталкиваюсь впервые. Была прочитана куча инфы о взаимодействии управляемого и неуправляемого кода, основные принципы понимаю, но совершенно неясно как же обёртывать именно класс, и как потом к нему получить доступ (скажем из с++), ибо P/Invoke позволяет импортировать только функции. Попытки возвращать указатель на экземпляр класса успехом не увенчались.

Comment: учитывая, что c++/cli - это сильно испорченный C#, то никаких проблем с доступом быть не должно. Вот с чистым с++ (который не .net) - будет сложнее.

С делфи проблем нет, если это дотнетовская версия. В противном случае нужно будет делать COM объект.

Comment: проблем доступа к C# из cli нет. непонятно как использовать классы-обёртки в cli из чистых плюсов и из недотнетовской делфи. про COM слышу в сотый раз, но адекватных понятных описаний использования библиотеки таким образом не найдено. Дайте пожалуйста какие-нибудь ссыли с примерами, если есть...

Comment: Спасибо! буду изучать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

задачу нужно разбить на две половинки - создать com объект и второе - использовать его на целевой платформе. Я привел для случая с делфи.

- [Turn a simple C# DLL into a COM interop component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092553/turn-a-simple-c-sharp-dll-into-a-com-interop-component)

  ### - [Example COM Class (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3fd4a20.aspx)
- [An Introduction to COM Programming with Delphi (4 / 6)](http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/aa121404a.htm)
- [Delphi и COM (Часть 1)](http://www.interface.ru/borland/decom_1.htm)